# Uploading data doesn't really upload and with no error in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365

I have this code, but I get the error described in the title: 
"The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed."

** I've replaced PUT by POST now**

If I replace "PUT" by "POST" it seems to work as I don't get an error, but it does not upload any file.
I'm trying to upload a file to a document library in sharepoint (office 365)

```
public static void UploadTest()
        {
            WebClient w = new WebClient();

            w.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            var ua = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
            w.Headers["Accept"] = "/";
            w.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, ua);
            byte[] bFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\t.txt");
            string ulr = @"http://www.website.com/uploadfolder/";
            System.Uri oUri = new System.Uri(ulr);

            try
            {
                w.UploadData(oUri, "POST", bFile);
                w.UploadDataCompleted += new UploadDataCompletedEventHandler(oWebClient_UploadDataCompleted);
                Console.WriteLine("Uri:" + oUri);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex; 
                          }

            finally
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: `PUT` is obviously not the correct method.  As a first guess without trying to look into Sharepoint at all, should you be using `POST` instead?

Comment: @DanPuzey "*`PUT` is obviously not the correct method*" - not sure why you are so adamant here, `PUT` can also be used to create resources as well as modifying (at least from a REST point of view).

Comment: Looks like he is right using `PUT`, so it must be a credentials problem. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658024/how-can-i-upload-files-to-office365-sharepoint-with-perl and http://msmvps.com/blogs/sundar_narasiman/archive/2011/11/30/upload-large-documents-to-sharepoint-site-using-webclient-class.aspx

Comment: It's no credential problem, thanks. Downloading does work, now trying to fix uploading with same credentials (I'm administrator (Full access) at the sharepoint)

Comment: @James: well, the error message is "Method not allowed."  For whatever reason, `PUT` isn't something that the client can call - that could be authorisation related, or it could be that the method should be `POST`.  I did say that it was a first guess!

Comment: @DanPuzey I've changed it to POST, it does not give me an error. But it does not upload the file?

Comment: @DanPuzey If it's authorisation related I would consider it bad design as it should realistically be returning a 403. I assumed `POST` however it does appear that `PUT` is the correct verb. @Robuust do you get any specific message returned along with the 405?

Comment: @James only the one I showed before. I replaced PUT by POST now, it does not give an error but neither does it really upload the file..

Comment: @Robuust I would suggest running a HTTP debugger like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and see what's being as part of your request and what information is being sent back as the response. Might help you trace where it's falling over.

Comment: @James: I agree RE: authorisation - that's why my first guess was to change the verb! :)

Comment: Alright it could be an authorisation function - but how can I update this? Any ideaS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem regarding access with credentials and logging in.
Something seems to go wrong when I try to connect, as I can download a corrupt file when I remove the w.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user,pass);

I'm trying a total new way around now, thanks for replying.